# How to send data (List<Customer> customers ) as input of an RS query (URI

Tags: web-services, rest, post, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS Jersey WebService that I am trying to accept an XML data (or JSON) and return the a `String` response showing the total number of records passed.

Here is my Service Code:

```
@Path("customers")
@Singleton
public class CustomersResource {
...
    @POST
    @Path("addall")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Consumes(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String addCustomers(List<Customer> customerList) {
        return "success : received " + customerList.size() ;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webresource = client.resource( "http://localhost:8080/restdemo/services/customers/addall");

    String input  = "<customerList><customer><name>name1</name></customer><customer><name>name2</name></customer></customerList>";
    String response = webresource.type("application/xml").post( String.class, input );
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
    at restdemoclient.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

I will appreciate any help or pointer to any example code which could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample which demostrates required functionality: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/samples/jaxb/1.12/jaxb-1.12-project.zip

[Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) should be useful for you as well.